# Jasper Reports: 2 Column subreport doesn't split evenly on the second page of report

Tags: jasper-reports, overflow, multiple-columns, subreport

**Problem:**

I've got a two column subreport that has a lot of data in it.  Where it appears on the first page of my main report it splits the data evenly into two columns.  However, when it overflows on to the second page it renders the two columns of data as one column that runs the length of the second page pushing all the rest of my report to a third page.

[image: Problem with 2 column subreport]

**Expectation:**

On the second page, split the subreport in half and render it as two columns.

---

Parent Report - ThiraPresubmissionThreat.jrxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 7.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.8.1-3d4b87119c827be13776e451fb3738062f84a87d  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ThiraPresubmissionThreat" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="468" leftMargin="72" rightMargin="72" topMargin="36" bottomMargin="36" uuid="da08ff4d-c3ae-4475-bf66-622c167cd036">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <parameter name="domainId" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <parameter name="domainName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="assessmentYear" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="thira_threat_id" class="java.lang.Long">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="thira_threat_id"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="thira_threat"/>
    </field>
    <field name="thira_threat_name" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="thira_threat_name"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="thira_threat"/>
    </field>
    <field name="category_name" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="category_name"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="list_item"/>
    </field>
    <field name="type_name" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="type_name"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="list_item"/>
    </field>
    <field name="terrorism" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="terrorism"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="thira_threat"/>
    </field>
    <field name="description" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="description"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="thira_threat"/>
    </field>
    <field name="source_use_other" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="source_use_other"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="thira_threat"/>
    </field>
    <field name="standardized_impact_count" class="java.lang.Long">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="standardized_impact_count"/>
    </field>
    <variable name="showedHeader" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    <group name="ThiraThreatGroup" isStartNewPage="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{thira_threat_id}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="26">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} < 1]]></printWhenExpression>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="468" height="26" forecolor="#003366" uuid="4b9bdcca-bf39-4c91-a90a-8277f39b4f6f"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="18" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[THIRA Step 1 and 2: Threats, Hazards, and Context]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
            <band height="26">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="468" height="26" forecolor="#006699" uuid="9e2e21b1-28a1-4090-bb48-7e9bf9978b2b"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Threat/Hazard: " + $F{thira_threat_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="36" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="140" y="0" width="327" height="21" uuid="f432ca22-5aec-4bc8-b18a-913153f96107"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[THIRA Steps 1 and 2: Threats, Hazards, and Context]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="24">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="156" height="24" uuid="79939e1e-d35d-42c2-a562-379065f3e61b"/>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Dashed"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<b>Category:</b> " + $F{category_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="156" y="0" width="156" height="24" uuid="3039ff87-96a1-4833-b79a-f95ba2732852"/>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Dashed"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<b>Type:</b> " + $F{type_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="312" y="0" width="156" height="24" uuid="f11dbd41-52a3-493e-9b22-4e66f5cc6432"/>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Dashed"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<b>Terrorism:</b> " + (Boolean.TRUE.equals($F{terrorism}) ? "Yes" : "No")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="48">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="23" width="468" height="17" uuid="2014321f-051a-4929-82dc-a082967d4399"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{description}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="4" width="160" height="18" uuid="847a9bfc-bf40-468b-9b9b-1379d21ef518"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Context Description:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
        <band height="51" splitType="Immediate">
            <subreport overflowType="Stretch">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="468" height="40" uuid="24a00653-b03e-40a8-91f5-25e823c4cdcb"/>
                <subreportParameter name="thiraThreatId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{thira_threat_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="rowCount">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{standardized_impact_count}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ThiraPresubmissionThreatStandardizedImpact.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="49" splitType="Immediate">
            <subreport overflowType="Stretch">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="468" height="40" uuid="24a00653-b03e-40a8-91f5-25e823c4cdcb"/>
                <subreportParameter name="thiraThreatId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{thira_threat_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ThiraPresubmissionThreatNonStandardizedImpact.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="100">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="50" width="234" height="39" uuid="d95d9f54-9012-4490-ad26-f4c3005cc3ae">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="20" width="234" height="30" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#003366" uuid="b25a4865-dd52-4ef1-9b0a-2abcbe8c8ad6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="d52ebdc1-3ca9-49b3-a716-1714c5b60ef8"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Source Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="234" y="20" width="234" height="30" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#003366" uuid="c97e4632-24a5-4b60-b1ca-fc002ec4537b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="152033f6-eaab-4499-ab58-c3548c2cfd7e"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Sources Used to Develop Context Description and Calculate Impacts (Optional)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="234" y="50" width="234" height="39" uuid="5aaf0b2f-5803-4e6c-aed7-f2b6e54d7188">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="152033f6-eaab-4499-ab58-c3548c2cfd7e"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.x" value="-1"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.y" value="1"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.weight.x" value="1.0"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.weight.y" value="1.0"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.rowspan" value="1"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.colspan" value="1"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.layout.grid.weight.fixed" value="false"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{source_use_other}]]></textFieldExpression>
                <patternExpression><![CDATA["#,###"]]></patternExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="50" width="234" height="39" uuid="b71f36e7-afbe-4555-82ef-fbc88b434bf2">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="thiraThreatId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{thira_threat_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ThiraPresubmissionThreatSource.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="240" height="20" uuid="8db3f369-d844-4d5f-bb9c-3fdc932e62ec"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Source Identification]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="36" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="468" height="20" uuid="c87e3768-a59f-4b8a-8afb-0e3500f9a5a7"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[FOR OFFICIAL USE ONLY]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField evaluationTime="Master">
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="468" height="16" uuid="88a6b8f6-e1cc-4323-998a-5947ef7edb96"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{assessmentYear} + " " + $P{domainName} + " THIRA | Page " + $V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE} + " of " + $V{MASTER_TOTAL_PAGES}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Subreport - ThiraPresubmissionThreatStandardizedImpact.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 7.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.8.1-3d4b87119c827be13776e451fb3738062f84a87d  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ThiraPresubmissionThreatStandardizedImpact" columnCount="2" pageWidth="468" pageHeight="400" columnWidth="234" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="02534ce9-84f1-475b-b3e5-50b7a6169869">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <parameter name="thiraThreatId" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <parameter name="rowCount" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="impact_category" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="impact_category"/>
    </field>
    <field name="impact_number" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="impact_number"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="thira_threat_standardized_impact"/>
    </field>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="176" height="20" uuid="961a7a93-002d-4c26-b471-851ef564fa1b"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Standardized Impact Estimates]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#003366" uuid="86d37fcc-f35c-4b6b-8687-4eda91520bc6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="d52ebdc1-3ca9-49b3-a716-1714c5b60ef8"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Impact Category]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="160" y="0" width="74" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#003366" uuid="0991a29e-5133-4200-b469-6b13ef47e47c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="152033f6-eaab-4499-ab58-c3548c2cfd7e"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Estimate]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Prevent">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="20" uuid="4c95062b-8d6c-42ad-8f78-d7f6d98495a6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="d52ebdc1-3ca9-49b3-a716-1714c5b60ef8"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{impact_category}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="160" y="0" width="74" height="20" uuid="8aad177b-e4c4-4c49-b4c5-379612844506">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="152033f6-eaab-4499-ab58-c3548c2cfd7e"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#BFBFBF"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{impact_number}]]></textFieldExpression>
                <patternExpression><![CDATA["#,###"]]></patternExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: please share the relevant jrxml file

Comment: @Lakshan how do you normally share the jrxml?  Should i give the actual file with the proprietary sensitive stuff stripped out or make a dummy file connected to a generic datasource?

Comment: put the jrxml content on above question as a code block. for more info, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189

Comment: Thanks! Updated with jrxml.

Comment: your sub report is located in the first column (`Source Name`) of parent report. so it renders as a single column on the left side of whole report (first page, second page so on). second column (`Optional`) of the parent report hold the `source_use_other` field's value

Comment: That's the wrong subreport.  Look for ThiraPresubmissionThreatStandardizedImpact in the parent.

Answer (score 1):

try with following solution,

set the Print Order property of the sub report (ThiraPresubmissionThreatStandardizedImpact) to Horizontal as follows,

Properties (tab) > Advanced (tab) > Page Columns > Print Order

ThiraPresubmissionThreatStandardizedImpact.jrxml

```
<jasperReport ...... name="ThiraPresubmissionThreatStandardizedImpact" printOrder="Horizontal" .....>
.......
</jasperReport>
```

output under the above config (expected output)

[image]

current output

[image]

Comment: I can't set it to horizontal because it cuts off the data in the row because the detail band won't stretch in horizontal flow -- by design (https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/10701).

Comment: set `printOrder` to `Horizontal`, you can get expected output. please refer above modified answer

Comment: Thanks Lakshan.  I tried it again and when I switch to horizontal print order, it truncates the data in the row, so unfortunately that won't work for me.

Comment: Please update the quection with your modified sub report's source and output

Comment: Lakshan, it didn't help my situation, so no need to update my source.  That just confuses the original issue.